# when query running server shutdown restart

Tags: php, mysql, server

I'am running a php script. It's containing sql query for example update or delete and i have 30 mil records. I want to learn when script is running for example 1 mil records updated then server shutdown what about to other records. If server is restarting does query will be go on or stop? I'm tested to localhost. Running a insert query for 1 mil records. Then stopped the apache2. After started the apache2 query is stop. But i don't test it on a server. Actually i want to learn server action when restarting.

Comment: it will be like the insert , as the connection is stopped, the script stops also. if te server is unrealiable you should put all into transaction, so that as long it os not commited, it will rollback

Comment: when i use transaction for 30 mil records is there a memory limit for this?

Comment: no, memory will not be the issue but time, php has always a very short time limit,. Eevry database has a chapter on bulk inserts, that should be read carefully. if you really need to do it copy the sql file to te server and run the mysql shell, also it woll not time out.

Comment: Thank you again. I'm not a database specialist. I've been a php core developer for over 15 years. I have developed hundreds projects.  Even the last developed big system Electronic Document Management System(EDMS). I have only used basic select parametres "*" or "id" vs. But i never used complicated sql queries like "distinct or join". First time i need something like this and there is no database specialist at the company I work. mysql shell i used this all the time. I was wondering if there is another way. So thank you again may be i use transaction i wish somebody else use it :)